# Error uploading file as String and getting response

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

Hello I am building an app in Spring Boot and I have to upload an xml file and get a response. I keep getting 415 unsupported media type. I should get an xml response.

Here is the code:

Controller:

```
 @PostMapping("/")
    public String postIndex(@RequestParam("fisier") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
        
String url = "http://xxx/FCTEL/rest/transformare/UBL";
        

       
     
URI uriLink = URI.create(url);
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();

//headers.set("serial_certificate", serial);
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
RestCall rc = new RestCall();
rc.body = new String(file.getBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
RequestEntity<String> reqEntity = new RequestEntity<String>(rc.body, headers, HttpMethod.POST, uriLink);
String response = restTemplate.postForObject(uriLink, reqEntity, String.class);
System.out.println(response);
File f = new File(response);
    return "index";
    
    
}
```

This is the error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$UnsupportedMediaType: 415 : " 
{"timestamp":"2022-07-05T05:39:01.445+00:00","status":415,"error":"Unsupported Media 
Type","path":"/FCTEL/rest/transformare/UBL"}"
```

The error stack shows that the code line with the problem where it fails is:

```
String response = restTemplate.postForObject(uriLink, reqEntity, String.class);
```

Can please someone tell me what I am doing wrong or give me an working example. Thanks

Comment: This code looks strange with all the lack of formatting, the fact that a rest endpoint is used to upload a file somewhere else (why?) and the code that apparently doesn't do anything (e.g. `File f = new File(response)`). It seems like you're just fiddling around with some tutorial so doesn't that one tell you what to do? In case it doesn't here's one that a quick search for "spring resttemplate upload multipart" came up with: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-rest-template-multipart-upload

Comment: Btw, the error already tells you what the problem is: "Unsupported Media Type". Your code doesn't seem to tell the server anywhere what it is going to send. Try adding `headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);`.

Comment: To add to @Thomas answer, also add `consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA` in your @PostMapping